# Should the 'on-topic' and 'offtopic-questions' tags become synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that the tags on this site called [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [offtopic-questions](/questions/tagged/offtopic-questions) should be made synonyms of each other, and yes, it may be argued that they are actually complete opposites of each other, however asking about what is on-topic is the same more or less as asking what is not off-topic, and visa versa, so is there a place where one would definitely be used over the other?
I don't think so, so I think that they should be made as synonyms of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the sane solution is the one adopted by Meta Stack Overflow: use a [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag, of which [offtopic-questions](/questions/tagged/offtopic-questions) and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) are [synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms).